# OpenCV detect horizontal and vertical lines

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am quite a noob when it comes to image processing. I choosed OpenCV to make my first steps. I was searching for a WYSIWYG editor to play around with the features OpenCV offers but I couldn't find.

My current problem is to detect the horizontal and vertical black lines in this picture going from most left to most right and from most top to most bottom:

[image: Picture]

I found out I can use HoughLinesP for this but the only parameter I am sure it is correct is the the minLineLength of the line. Actually it doesn't find any lines. I am reading the image as a grayscaled image but I am not sure if I need to make use of Canny before applying it to HoughLinesP.

Thanks for help.

Here is some C# code:

```cs
        var image = CvInvoke.Imread(filePath, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ImreadModes.Grayscale);
        var lines = CvInvoke.HoughLinesP(image, 1, 1, 0, image.Height);
```

As @Micka mentioned I should invert the image and I tried further steps to make it even simpler I started with a simple cross picture:

[image: 9x9 cross]

```cs
        var image = CvInvoke.Imread("cross.png", Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ImreadModes.Grayscale);
        CvInvoke.BitwiseNot(image, image);
        var lines = CvInvoke.HoughLinesP(image, rho: 1, theta: 1, 0, image.Height - 1);
```

But it detects only one line of length 8 but it should be 9 pixels long.

Comment: In every row, ignore first and last pixel, if every other pixel is black, there is a black line.

Comment: If you want to use houghlines, invert the image, so that the black lines become white instead. White is the "foreground" in most algorithms that assume active and inactive pixels.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I simplified it even more. I just tried to use a simple 9x9 cross to detect the lines but I don't get the result I thought I would get. 2 lines (1 horizonal, 1 vertical, both are of 9 pixels length)

Comment: This problem doesn't need Hough or anything else complicated. Add all pixel values along rows. Some rows will add to 0. These are the black lines. Repeat with columns. Done.

Comment: Similar approach to this... look at the green arrows https://stackoverflow.com/a/63174271/2836621