How to split based on gridlines?
I have an image like this:-

I want to split them into rows based on the lines and then apply ocr on it and store them in a list.
The latter part is easy but I'm not sure how to achieve the first task, I'm new to image processing and would love some guidance
I have tried my best to do the same referring to similar problem posts with no avail.

You probably want Hough lines. One example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39925278/7750891

If the horizontal lines are truly horizontal, you can just sum, or average, the pixels across the image and if they are largely black, they will sum/average to near zero. Explicitly, I mean np.sum(image, axis=1) See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63174271/2836621

Nobody wants Hough lines. Nobody should want Hough lines. At best, that'll give you some lines. Then you'll have to puzzle them together into a table.

Not exactly the same problem, but very closely related answers: Here and here.

You could invert your image so the lines are white on a black background and then use np.count_nonzero() along axis=1 (see https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) and then find the high count values. Perhaps threshold to remove the low count values to make the high ones stand out.
